# Https POST request using form gives a json.txt file as response

Tags: html, json, http, servlets

I am using a form to fire a https post request

```
    <form id="myForm1" action="https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token" method="POST" >
<input type="hidden" value="<%=str%>" name="code"/>
<input type="hidden" value="XXXXXXXXX.apps.googleusercontent.com" name="client_id"/>
<input type="hidden" value="XXXXXXXXX" name="client_secret"/>
<input type="hidden" value="http://localhost:8080/tester/login.do" name="redirect_uri">
<input type="hidden" value="authorization_code" name="grant_type"/>
<input type="submit" value="submit"/>
</form>
```

I want to get a Http Response from this containing the access token and related info but submitting this for google authorization downloads a json.txt file containing the response.
http//:../login.do is a servlet.
Also, the application is not entering the servlet defined at the redirect_url.
One more thing, I am able to redirect to only the first url in the list of Redirect URl's in Google Developers console....
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: consider using [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/)

Comment: @bansi i do not know how to use jquery and i just want to get the response as a HttpRequest object rather than a txt file

Comment: check the link I have posted on by first comment there is good sample there. also check http://learn.jquery.com/ajax/ and http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jquery/ajax-jquery-post.htm

Comment: @bansi thanks for the links, I'll read through them but I would also like to know what I am doing wrong in the above method or why is the google server responding to my request with a txt file.

Comment: not sure, but the only error i can see is `</input>` is invalid HTML in line 5

Comment: @bansi still getting the same result after rectifying that